# Undefined local variable or method `current_submission' for #<OrdersController:0x000000056a6a30>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create an app for managing an academic conference. Users will sign in and submit abstracts for consideration of being presented at our annual conference. I have followed the "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial" for most of what I have done. My modifications include adding a Submission model, a Registration model, and an Order model. The Submission model belongs_to the User model and has_one order.

I am trying to follow the Railscast 145/146 episodes about integrating PayPal Express checkout using ActiveMerchant. My goal is to put a PayPal checkout button on the submissions show.html.erb page so that after the author has submitted his abstract he can pay the submission fee right away.

The error arises from the following code after I have submitted the order:

```
class OrdersController < InheritedResources::Base

  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = current_submission.orders.build_order(params[:order])

    @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
    if @order.save

      # flash[:notice] = "Successfully created order."
      #redirect_to orders_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

From what I have read, I think the problem has to do with how orders are related to submissions. Each submission should have a related order entry, so in the Order table there should be a submission_id. I am really confused about how this works.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Is there a user guide that you would recommend that I read? There seems to be a lot of conflicting information out there between the different versions of Rails. I am using Rails 3.0.10.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no context for `current_submission`; how have you setup your resources?  I'm also not to sure about the User 'has_one' Order association.

Comment: My routes.rb file contains: resources :submissions I realize that submissions is plural. I thought resources pointed towards the controller rather than the model.

Comment: Mind updating your model relations, something doesn't feel right as per your earlier comments.

Comment: So the User signs up and makes a single submission of multiple abstracts, hence only being allowed one order?

Comment: Users sign up and may make more than one submission. Each submission is a different abstract. Each time they make a submission they have to pay a submission fee. The submission fees will be deducted from the registration fees later. (Submission fees are non-refundable whereas registration fees can be refunded if the author doesn't go to the conference.)

Comment: Oder.rb contains belongs_to :submission and Submission.rb contains has_one :order     I was thinking that there is a one-to-one relationship between a submission and an order. I thought that this was best because authors typically don't enter all of their submissions at the same time. Most authors have only one submmission.

Comment: See my updated comments below =)

Answer (score 2):

You should setup your resources as

```
resources :submissions do
  resource :order
end
```

This way your params will reflect the particular submission being accessed via an `:id` attribute.  Your `orders#create` action would then change to

```
@submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])
@order = @submission.orders.build_order(params[:order])
```

The relation you have reflected above seems to indicate `Submission has_many :orders`.  Regarding your comment

> The Submission model belongs_to the User model and has_one order.

In that case you need to change the above to - notice how orders becomes order:

```
@order = @submission.order.build_order(params[:order])
```

So your relationships are Submission has_one :order; Order :belongs_to :submission and User :has_one :submission?

**Update**

Based on your comments describing your requirements, your relationships need to change as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :submissions, :through => :orders

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this table needs attributes user_id and session_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :session

  validates :submission_id, :uniqueness => true

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, :through => :orders
```

Since I've placed a uniqueness constraint on the join table, it will ensure that a particular `submission_id` can only occur once in any record.  You can setup your controller using 'orders' like before and it'll most likely be `@submission = Submission.find(params[:id])` rather than `@submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])` since orders is a singular resource.

If you need further assistance with this drop me an email at mike at bsodmike dot com.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the changes you suggested, trying both order and orders. Now I am getting the error "no route matches /orders". I added resource :orders to the routes.db file and it appears to work. Thank you again for generous help.

Comment: No it is now giving me the error "Couldn't find Submission without an ID"

Comment: Check the params hash on whether you should use `:id`: or `:submission_id`.  Also make sure your table migrations are correct - all `belongs_to` tables need a foreign key that you need to create, i.e. this isn't done by Rails for you.